# Python-Celery increase concurrency on worker

Tags: python, celery

**TL;DR**

Is it possible to increase or decrease concurrency on a **running** Celery worker **without** restarting it?

I'm using celery 4.0.0 with RabbitMQ as a broker on ubuntu 14.10

**My Usecase**

I am frequently facing a large queue of tasks, most of which primarily execute an HTTP-Request and do some minor processing. I have the worker running on a fairly powerful machine and would like to maximize resource utilization on it. This is not a problem most of the time, except when dealing with these large number of HTTP-Requests, which might timeout or take a very long time to respond etc. When dealing with these, I'd like to temporarily increase the `--concurrency`-parameter, without actually having to restart the worker.

Currently I'm running celery with `--concurrency  150`, but this will only get the servers bottleneck (CPU) to about ~10% utilization. I suppose one solution would be to spawn another 150-concurrency worker for that time period and kill it later, but that might add complexity down the road. I'd like to stick to 1 worker/machine if at all possible.

Comment: How about the autoscaling option: http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/userguide/workers.html#autoscaling

Comment: In principal I like the Idea of using autoscaling better than what I came up with. However, the docs are not at all clear on how to go about subclassing it and adding your own logic to it.
Mind you, I'm now stuck on the fact that celery throws errors everywhere when one tries to go beyond 169 processes, but thats probably something for github.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It would probably be possible to use celeries builtin [autoscaling](http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/userguide/workers.html#autoscaling) (thanks Philip Tzou) by subclassing it. Unfortunately celeries Autoscale-functionality is quite poorly documented.

However, after doing some more digging, I came across [celery.app.control](http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/reference/celery.app.control.html), which (among other things) allows for scaling by sending messages to the worker via RabbitMQ. Here's a little example of how one could go about this:

```
import os, time
from celery import Celery
from celery.app.control import Control

app = Celery()
controller = Control(app)

while True:
    n=5 # the numer of processes to add/remove
    upper_load_threshold = 6
    lower_load_threshold = 4
    if os.getloadavg()[0] <= lower_load_threshold: # we're looking at the 5 min load avg here
        controller.pool_grow(n)
    elif os.getloadavg()[0] >= upper_load_threshold:
        controller.pool_shrink(n)
    time.sleep(10)
```